# Spark App Works Only in Standalone but not able to connect to master?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala 2.10 spark 1.5.0 sbt app I am developing in eclipse. In my main method, I have:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[2]", "My Spark App")

// followed by operations to do things with the spark context to count up lines in a file
```

When I run this application within the eclipse IDE, it works and outputs what I expect the result to be, but when I change the spark context to connect to my cluster using:

```
val master = "spark://My-Hostname-From-The-Spark-Master-Page.local:7077"
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My Spark App").setMaster(master)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I get errors like:

```
WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@My-Hostname-From-The-Spark-Master-Page.local:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

What gives? How can I get my job to run with the existing master and slave nodes I started up? I know spark-submit is recommended, but arn't applications like Zepplin and Notebook designed to use spark without having to "spark-submit"?

Comment: I had the same problem, AFAIK `spark-submit` is the only way to submit to a cluster. However you *can* automate submitting with custom shell scripts and IDE features.

Comment: Are you in the same network as the cluster? The executors need to be able to connect to the driver node (the machine you're starting the code with `SparkContext`).

Comment: @MehmetM.Inanc, this is not true, I always used spark in this manner and actually never used spark-submit. I would say this is a network/firewall/proxy problem as mentioned by Reactormonk.

Comment: I am on my local machine on OSX. I started a master and a single worker. I have no firewall... Using local without specifying configuration for master works. I dont get why master does not.

Comment: I don't see the problem with using spark-submit - it's an easy way to manage and launch your Spark applications.

Comment: You could try and connect to the master using spark-shell to make sure it is possible to connect.  e.g. spark-shell --master spark://IP:PORT

Comment: @Juh_ I can't tell for older versions, but even on a single node cluster, where network/firewall/proxy should not matter, I couldn't get it to work. I've used several master parameters, like `spark://localhost:7077`, `spark://hostname:7077`. Then it occured to me, in a distributed environment the binaries or code should be distributed to workers as well. This is exactly what `spark-submit` does, and running a binary off-the-grid shouldn't cut it.

Comment: @Gillespie, there is no problem using spark-submit, I just say it is not necessary.

Comment: @Mehmet, first of all, you should be using the spark address as written on the spark web page, not localhost/hostname/127.0.0.1, second there are functionalities to ship the jar to worker from within the spark driver (sc.addJar or something). Its not always practical, though. Now, if its is a problem of dep, then the job should start and produce NoClassDefFound error

Comment: @Rolando, no much idea. Did you check env variables (and spark conf maybe) are as getting started tutorials said they should?